# Django request.user.is_authenticated generating SSL errors using Apache2 Benchmark tool ab

Tags: django, ssl, apache2

In Django 1.5, I have a project built from scratch with nothing in it except the default files and the following:

```
urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'views.index'),
)


views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('So much fun...')
```

When I run Apache2 Benchmark tool as follows:

```
ab -n 2000 -c 150 https://myserver.com/
```

Everything is hunky dory.

Now, I change one thing to check for authentication....

```
views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse('So much fun...')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Need to log in.')
```

And running the ab benchmark tool again, I get the following errors (not every hit throws the error, but many of them do):

```
SSL handshake failed (1).
10044:error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01:rsa_pk1.c:100:
10044:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:697:
10044:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:bad signature:s3_clnt.c:1451:
```

At first this was all in middleware testing to see if the person needs to be sent to the login page, and I thought maybe it had to do with timing - messing with the request.user object while it was trying to process the request. After chasing this rabbit down the hole, I found it can just be in the view itself and it will throw these errors.

Anybody know what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: I just upgraded to Django 1.6.2 and tried it again, with the same result.

Comment: I also changed it to check for the request.user attribute id with the following: `if hasattr(request.user, 'id'):` and that is still throwing errors.

Comment: Just tried with a brand new signed certificate and key from startssl.com and still getting the same errors. What the heck could be going on here?

Comment: Hm, I feel like it might be an issue with how you configured SSL, and the Django code-change is a red herring, since you only get the error on some requests

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a setting in PostgreSQL. I connected to a local sqllite database and in a view, I returned an `HttpResponse` with `request.user.is_authenticated()` - NO ERRORS. I created a new Postgresql database, connected to that and ran the apache2 benchmark and the errors came back. I changed the view to get the first django `ContentType`, no call to request.user - ERRORS. Opened postgresql.conf and found a default `ssl = true`. Commented it and the errors stopped. `ssl=true` is generating SSL errors when I access the database and then run apache2 benchmark within a few seconds.